# The name WebHost does not exists in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm migrating from ASP.NET Core 1.x to v2.0 with the help of following post on docs.microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

I'm almost done with all the changes mentioned in that post. But there is one error that is causing troubles.

Here is my Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MeridiaCoreAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
            // delete all default configuration providers
            config.Sources.Clear();
                config.AddJsonFile("myconfig.json", optional: true);
            })
               .Build();
    }
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'WebHost' does not exist in the current context
```

Any solution, workaround or hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`WebHost` class resides `Microsoft.AspNetCore` assembly that comes with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` NuGet package. So to fix you problem install this NuGet package and add following `using` directive to your source file:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore;`

Comment: My integration manager does not want all dlls as Microsoft.AspNetCore.All includes 100+ assemblies to run a basic .Net Core application. Is there any way to include only the dependent assemblies to build and run the app?

Comment: Take look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: @ManishDubey yes.  [My answer is below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486724/209259).

Comment: The required package name is `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. Don't use the `.All` package or you will face compilation issues.

Answer (score 4):

As [CodeFuller's answer indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416338/209259) the `WebHost` class is available in the assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore`  If you don't need everything, you can just get the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore`.